# How does node's require functionality get installed on a server?

Tags: node.js, npm, require

My understanding is that you have to go through node in order to use the `require` functionality that pulls other files into a specific file's scope. How does this (or node in general) get deployed to production?

I tried having a folder with npm initialized inside and had an `index.html` referring to another script and using `require` in there but it didn't work. Unless I `node` that file, the `require` won't work. So how does node get onto the server?

Comment: You seem a bit confused here.  node runs Javascript files, not HTML files.  You use `require()` inside your JS files and those JS files are NOT inside of HTML files.  In fact, node doesn't run HTML files at all - those run in a browser and you don't use the node.js `require()` in Javascript run in the browser unless you get a browser-based library that implements its own version of a module loader.

Comment: `require()` is built into node.js and thus is available to any script run by node.js.  The same is true of all the other node.js built-in libraries such as `fs` or `net`.  You can only `require()` them in from code being run within node.js.

Comment: so when a browser runs an html file that has a script that uses require, where is node being run in order to execute the require? does the browser use something else in order to do that?

Comment: @stackjlei It doesn't! It will just report an error "require is not defined" and stop. That's why when your files hit the browser, there should be no `require` calls left, unless `require` is defined by your script. There are tools to help, e.g. http://browserify.org/